# EclipsePDT & PHPUnit error

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to use PHPUnit within Eclipse PDT and I get the following error in the console (EDIT: Eclipse's console):

```
Fatal error: Declaration of PHPUnitLogger::addFailure(Test $test, AssertionFailedError $e, $time): void must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener::addFailure(PHPUnit\Framework\Test $test, PHPUnit\Framework\AssertionFailedError $e, float $time): void in C:\Users\Iago\AppData\Local\Temp\phpunit_printer\PHPUnitLogger.php(415) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Also, I get a popup with "Cannot launch PHPUnit tests (port address 7478): Accept timed out.

If I try to run the test directly from (EDIT: a regular) console I get a "Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found" error (EDIT: I solved this one. It seems tests are working from a regular console now). I get that error as a red highlight on the editor too (EDIT: I still get it).

This is what my composer.json "require" and "autoload" look like:

```
"require" : {
    "php" : ">=7.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit" : "7",
    "phpunit/dbunit" : "4.0.0"
},
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "Championsweb\\" : "src/Championsweb",
        "Championsweb\\Controller\\" : "src/Championsweb/Controller",
        "Championsweb\\Model\\" : "src/Championsweb/Model",
        "Championsweb\\Model\\VO\\" : "src/Championsweb/Model/VO"
    }
}
```

This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
|
 -- config
 -- public
 -- src
 -- tests
 -- vendor
    |
     -- phpunit
 -- views
```

My Eclipse project build path includes vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src.

I also have PHPUnit Phar stored somewhere else in my hard drive and I have its route configured in Preferences > PHP > Tools > PHPUnit. Regarding this, I have the default communication port 7478, although I don't understand for what a communication port is needed.

Thank you in advance.